# A logarithm integral

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form

Calculate the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \ln(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{1-x}) }{ \sqrt{x} } \ dx
\end{align}
and show the value is negative.

Comment: did you try rewriting the numerator as $\frac{1}{2} \log x + \log (1-\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}})$ and then expanding the second logarithm in Taylor series?

Comment: Something doesn't feel right. If $x$ is close to $0$, the expression $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{1-x}$ in the denominator is negative. The integral will pick up an imaginary part!

Comment: it's value is obviously negative though because $\log s <0$ if $0 <s <1$

Comment: for $x<1/2$ the argument of the $\ln(\cdot)$ is negative!

Comment: Is it $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x}$ or $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x}$?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay it can't be $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1-x}$. In that case, the integral is positive according to WA.

Comment: Yes, I was just mentioning one possibility for the correctness of the integral.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large\left.\left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{1 - x}\right)\
\right \vert_{\quad x\ <\ {1 \over 2}}  \color{#c00000}{\LARGE < 0}}$.

Answer (score 4):

This integral cannot be real. The issue in Samrat's proof is that $\log(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{1-x})$ has sort of *jump* at $x = 1/2$.

Let us use the standard branch cut so that $\log(-x) = \log x + \pi i$ for $x > 0$. Then we can write

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{1-x})}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx
&= \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\log(\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{x}) + \pi i}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx \\
&\quad + \int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{\log(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{1-x})}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx \\
&= \sqrt{2}\pi i + I_{1} + I_{2},
\end{align*}

where

$$ I_{1} = \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\log(\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx
\quad \text{and} \quad
I_{2} = \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\log(\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{1-x}} \, dx. $$

For $I_{1}$, integration by parts shows that

\begin{align*}
I_{1} 
&= \left[ (2\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2}) \log(\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{x}) \right]_{0}^{1/2} \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{2\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{x}}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right) \, dx.
\end{align*}

(Here, the bizarre choice for the antiderivative is introduced to cancel out the logarithmic singularity.) Likewise,

\begin{align*}
I_{2} 
&= \left[ (\sqrt{2} - 2\sqrt{1-x}) \log(\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{x}) \right]_{0}^{1/2} \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\sqrt{2} - 2\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{x}}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right) \, dx.
\end{align*}

Adding them together,

$$I_{1} + I_{2} = - \int_{0}^{1/2} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right) \, dx = -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} = -2. $$

Therefore the final answer is

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{1-x})}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx = -2 + \sqrt{2}\pi i. $$

Comment: +1 this is also what I get by doing an integration by part before doing a contour integral.

Comment: It should be better to say that the question was ill posed.

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln (\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx\\=2\sqrt{x}\ln(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x})|_{0}^1-\int_{0}^1\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx$$ The first part is $0$ and the second integral is $$-1-1/2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x+1-x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx=-1-1/2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}d\theta=-1-\pi/2$$

Comment: The first part is $-2\sqrt{0}\log(-\sqrt{1})$

Comment: Yes, but that is $-2\cdot 0\cdot i(2k+1)\pi,\ k\in \mathbb{Z}$ which  is still $0$.

Comment: Ok. Nice $(+1)$

Comment: Independent of where the imaginary part of the original integral goes, the real part of the integral has to be $-2$ (WA evalulates $\int_0^1 \frac{\log|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{1-x}|}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ to $-2$.)